# ng-show doesn't work in Angular Google Maps InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code which I use to show `InfoWindow` (Angular Google Maps):

```
  $scope.showPoint = function(marker, eventName, point) {
    $scope.options.info.coords = point;
    $scope.geocode_result = true;
    $scope.options.info.show = true;
  };
```

Template:

```
<ui-gmap-window closeClick="closeInfoWindow" coords="options.info.coords" show="options.info.show">
      <div class="window-content">
        <h3 class="text-center">
          "{{ options.info.point.label }}"
        </h3>
        <div class="body">
          <hr />
          <div class="preloader" ng-show="geocode_result">
            <img src="img/preloader.gif" /><span><strong>Получение адреса...</strong></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ui-gmap-window>
```

As you can see, I use `ng-show` in my template, and I set `true` for its value, but `preloader` is still hidden. I can see window without the `preloader`. How to fix this code?

Comment: Have you try to open it in your debugger ?
Can you check if the img exists but is not displayed ? (I'm guessing a wrong path for your image ?)
Have you got any CSS on body / preloader ?